# @Transaction not working on multi datasource Spring Boot + MyBatis application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to configure Spring Boot + MyBatis application which should work with several datasources. I tried to do it similar to [sample here](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/issues/78#issuecomment-258064131).

Querying and updating data is working, but when I wrote the unit test, I found that @Transactional is not working. Transactions must work between all databases. It means that, if one method with @Transactional make updates on both databases then everything should rollback in case of exception.

It is a sample application for testing purposes and co-workers. After successful configuring the new applications will be configured and developed in similar manner.

Maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aze.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-one</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below are the configuration classes:

```
package com.aze.mybatis.sampleone;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Config to database BSCS (Oracle)

```
package com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.config;

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.dao", annotationClass = BscsDataSource.class, sqlSessionFactoryRef = BscsDatabaseConfig.SQL_SESSION_FACTORY_NAME)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BscsDatabaseConfig {

    static final String SQL_SESSION_FACTORY_NAME = "sessionFactoryBscs";
    private static final String TX_MANAGER = "txManagerBscs";

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceBscs")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bscs.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = TX_MANAGER)
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManagerBscs() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = BscsDatabaseConfig.SQL_SESSION_FACTORY_NAME)
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

}
```

Config to database ONSUBS (Oracle)

```
package com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.config;

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.dao", annotationClass = OnsubsDataSource.class, sqlSessionFactoryRef = OnsubsDatabaseConfig.SQL_SESSION_FACTORY_NAME)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class OnsubsDatabaseConfig {

    static final String SQL_SESSION_FACTORY_NAME = "sessionFactoryOnsubs";
    private static final String TX_MANAGER = "txManagerOnsubs";

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceOnsubs")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "onsubs.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = TX_MANAGER)
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManagerOnsubs() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = OnsubsDatabaseConfig.SQL_SESSION_FACTORY_NAME)
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

}
```

Annotation for BSCS:

```
package com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.config;

public @interface BscsDataSource {
}
```

and ONSUBS:

```
package com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.config;

public @interface OnsubsDataSource {
}
```

Mapper interface that should work with ONSUBS:

```
package com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.dao;

import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.config.OnsubsDataSource;
import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.domain.Payment;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

@Mapper
@OnsubsDataSource
public interface PaymentDao {

    Payment getPaymentById(@Param("paymentId") Integer paymentId);

}
```

and BSCS:

```
package com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.dao;

import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.config.BscsDataSource;
import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.domain.PostpaidBalance;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

@Mapper
@BscsDataSource
public interface PostpaidCustomerDao {

    PostpaidBalance getPostpaidBalance(@Param("customerId") Integer customerId);

    // BigDecimal amount may be used as second parameter, but I want to show, how to work with two parameters where second is object
    void updateDepositAmount(@Param("customerId") Integer customerId, @Param("balance") PostpaidBalance postpaidBalance);

    void updateAzFdlLastModUser(@Param("customerId") Integer customerId, @Param("username") String username);

}
```

Below is a code with @Transactional

```
package com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.service;

import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.dao.PaymentDao;
import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.dao.PostpaidCustomerDao;
import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.domain.Payment;
import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.domain.PostpaidBalance;
import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.exception.DataNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Service
public class PaymentServiceImpl implements PaymentService {

    private static final String MIN_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT = "150";

    @Autowired
    private PaymentDao paymentDao;

    @Autowired
    private PostpaidCustomerDao postpaidCustomerDao;

    @Override
    public PostpaidBalance getPostpaidBalance(Integer customerId) {
        PostpaidBalance balance = postpaidCustomerDao.getPostpaidBalance(customerId);

        if (balance == null) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException(String.format("Can't find any balance information for customer with customer_id = %d", customerId));
        }

        return balance;
    }

    // Note. By default rolling back on RuntimeException and Error but not on checked exceptions
    // If you want to rollback on check exception too then add "rollbackFor = Exception.class"
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Override
    public void updateDepositAmount(Integer customerId, PostpaidBalance postpaidBalance, String username) {
        postpaidCustomerDao.updateDepositAmount(customerId, postpaidBalance);

        // In case of @Transactional annotation, you can use method from the same class if it doesn't change data on database
        PostpaidBalance balance = getPostpaidBalance(customerId);

        // This logic is for showing that how the @Transactional annotation works.
        // Because of the exception, the previous transaction will rollback
        if (balance.getDeposit().compareTo(new BigDecimal(MIN_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT)) == -1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The customer can not have deposit less than " + MIN_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT);
        }

        // In case of @Transactional annotation, you must not (!!!) use method from the same (!) class if it changes data on database
        // That is why, postpaidCustomerDao.updateAzFdlLastModUser() used here instead of this.updateAzFdlLastModUser()
        postpaidCustomerDao.updateAzFdlLastModUser(customerId, username);

        // If there is no exception, the transaction will commit
    }
}
```

Below is the unit test code:

```
package com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.service;

import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.Application;
import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.config.BscsDatabaseConfig;
import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.config.OnsubsDatabaseConfig;
import com.aze.mybatis.sampleone.domain.PostpaidBalance;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class, OnsubsDatabaseConfig.class, BscsDatabaseConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations= "classpath:application.properties")
public class PaymentServiceImplTest extends Assert {


    // My goal is not to write a full and right unit tests, but just show you examples of working with MyBatis

    @Autowired
    private PaymentService paymentService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        assert paymentService != null;
    }

    @Test
    public void updateDepositAmount() throws Exception {
        final int customerId = 4301887; // not recommended way. Just for sample
        final String username = "ITCSC";
        boolean exceptionRaised = false;

        PostpaidBalance balance = paymentService.getPostpaidBalance(customerId);
        assertTrue("Find customer with deposit = 0", balance.getDeposit().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0);
        balance.setDeposit(BigDecimal.TEN);

        try {
            paymentService.updateDepositAmount(customerId, balance, username);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exceptionRaised = true;
        }

        assertTrue(exceptionRaised);
        balance = paymentService.getPostpaidBalance(customerId);
        // We check that transaction was rollback and amount was not changed
        assertTrue(balance.getDeposit().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0);

        final BigDecimal minDepositAmount = new BigDecimal("150");
        balance.setDeposit(minDepositAmount);
        paymentService.updateDepositAmount(customerId, balance, username);

        balance = paymentService.getPostpaidBalance(customerId);
        assertTrue(balance.getDeposit().compareTo(minDepositAmount) != -1);
    }
}
```

Unit test fails on `assertTrue(balance.getDeposit().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0);`. The I check the database and see that first update `postpaidCustomerDao.updateDepositAmount(customerId, postpaidBalance);` was not rollback despite the @Transactional annotation.

Please help to solve problem.

Comment: Have you looked at JtaTransactionManager for distributed transactions?

Comment: No, haven't looked at JtaTransactionManager. As you can see here both update actions are in one DAO (at one database) postpaidCustomerDao. Transaction management doesn't work even at one database. Tomorrow I'll try JtaTransactionManager.

Comment: Ah yes my bad thought it hit both data sources. Perhaps another thing to consider is that you're using @Transactional without specifying the specific transaction manger and that your primary data source/transaction manager is Onsubs while your test is hitting PostpaidCustomerDao which is using BscsDataSource

Comment: But I declared transaction manager at BscsDatabaseConfig


    @Bean(name = TX_MANAGER)
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManagerBscs() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

Comment: Yes but how does @Transctional know which oh the two transaction managers you declared to use in your instance given you did not specify? My understanding is that is would default to primary

Comment: I believe I was able to replicate this in a sample project I have and confirm my suspicion. Using Transactional with a primary transaction manager that is not tied to the data source I'm updating commits despite an error being thrown but if I update Transaction to specify the appropriate transaction manager the update is rolled back as expected

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple TransactionManagers, you'll need to reference the one you want to use for `@Transactional` using Bean names or Qualifiers.

In your Java Config:

```
@Bean("myTM")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(myDatasource());
}
```

In Services:

```
@Transactional("myTM")
public void insertWithException(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
}
```

I debug'd my app to see how Spring chooses the TransactionManager. This is done in `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport#determineTransactionManager`

```
/**
 * Determine the specific transaction manager to use for the given transaction.
 */
protected PlatformTransactionManager determineTransactionManager(TransactionAttribute txAttr) {
    // Do not attempt to lookup tx manager if no tx attributes are set
    if (txAttr == null || this.beanFactory == null) {
        return getTransactionManager();
    }
    String qualifier = txAttr.getQualifier();
    if (StringUtils.hasText(qualifier)) {
        return determineQualifiedTransactionManager(qualifier);
    }
    else if (StringUtils.hasText(this.transactionManagerBeanName)) {
        return determineQualifiedTransactionManager(this.transactionManagerBeanName);
    }
    else {
        PlatformTransactionManager defaultTransactionManager = getTransactionManager();
        if (defaultTransactionManager == null) {
            defaultTransactionManager = this.transactionManagerCache.get(DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_KEY);
            if (defaultTransactionManager == null) {
                defaultTransactionManager = this.beanFactory.getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class);
                this.transactionManagerCache.putIfAbsent(
                        DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_KEY, defaultTransactionManager);
            }
        }
        return defaultTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

So it's just getting the default primary `PlatformTransactionManager` bean.